# How do I populate a select options in a form in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, select, html-select

I have a form with many select options. I need to populate these. Initially via JSON, but later I will populate from my database.

How do I go about this.

This will be my html.

```
<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="card">
    <form>
        <div class="card-header">Search for a Property</div>
        <div class="card-body">

          <!-- County and Town Label-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label class="ml-1" for="county">County</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="town">Town</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <!-- County Column -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select class ="form-control" id="county" name="county">
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <select class="form-control" name="town">
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will be my js.

Is there a way to just populate arrays for each select I need and loop through each item.

```
export class PropertySearchComponent implements OnInit {

  searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private advertService: AdvertService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createSearchForm();
  }

  createSearchForm() {
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      town: [, Validators.required],
      county: [, Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: share the json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate some arrays in your `.ts` file (I'm assuming you're using TypeScript) such as this one:

```
counties: string[] = ['County1', 'County2', 'County3'];
```

Then in the template file:

```
<select class ="form-control" id="county" name="county">
  <option value="">Please select a county</option>
  <option *ngFor="let county of counties"
          [value]="county">{{county}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Angular just needs to know what to loop through and have a reference to it in your template. This is an excellent reference: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/model-driven/